# Server Error in " <authentication mode="None" /> "

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm following a tutorial that says:

1 - The first step before adding ASP NET Identity is to disable the default authentication mechanism of the application server (IIS) because the framework uses its own. To do this, add the following configuration in the "system.web" section of the Web.config file:

```
 <authentication mode="None" />
```

So, my web.config now looks like this:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

but when I try to run the application, I get the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 35:
>
> Line 36: < system.web >
>
> Line 37: < authentication mode="None" / >
>
> Line 38: < compilation >
>
> Line 39: < assemblies >

I tried to search for answers, but I found nothing. Specially considering that, as this computer is not mine, I can't do anything that requires admin permissions, so, I can't follow [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx) guide to configure a virtual directory as IIS application .

Comment: Which web.config did you modify? Is it in the root of your application code? And is the root of your application code configured as a site or virtual application in IIS? Note, you don't want a virtual directory, you want either a website or virtual application.

Comment: I was going to say I had just one web.config but I realised I had two. I tried to chance the <authentication mode="None" /> from one to another, and it now works! XD thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try the following steps:

- Open IIS Manager
- Expand the tree: `Sites` >> `Default Web Site`
- Right click on your site and choose `Convert to Application` >> `OK`

Answer (score 2):

I had the error, too.

The answer is:
"This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

A virtual directory being configured as an application in IIS. Just try it, and it will ok

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although this might answer the question, consider adding explanation and links to support your claims, which adds more basis to your answer.